# How to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: android, networkonmainthread

I have an Activity that performs some Network operations in `onCreate()`.

The point is that I have to launch another Activity after the data collection is completed.

How do I make sure the network operations on my `onCreate()` are completed before I start the other Activity so that I avoid the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` error?

Comment: use an async task, there are plenty of questions regarding them

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html. use asynctask or create a new thread and run network related operation in the thread.

Comment: @tyczj that is the point! I am using AsyncTasks but when I launch the other Activity they are not finished an therefore the  NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @LisaAnne post your code

Comment: @LisaAnne if you really were using an async task then you would not be getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` since an async task runs in a separate thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455858/using-asynctask-to-speed-up-android-app-launch-time) to get you started using an `AsyncTask`. You do all of your network operations in `doInBackground()` then you can start your next `Activity` in `onPostExecute()` which will run after `doInBackground()` has finished.

`doInBackground()` returns its result to `onPostExecute()` so if you start your `Activity` there then your network operations will be finished.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I have several AsyncTasks, and it is not possible to know many...

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't make sense without some code and context of your situation and how you are using them. We need more clarity for a better answer. The way your question was stated, it didn't sound like you new about `AsyncTask`.

Comment: You could have each task start from the previous one or use a timer and use `getStatus()` to check the progress of each but I'm sure there's a better way if you explain what you have and show how you are doing it

Comment: If you really have multiple tasks you should NOT chain them together by starting the next one in the previous tasks onPostExecute. That would be a nightmare to debug. You should set your `AsyncTask` up as seperate classes, use a call back to your starting activity so you know when the task is done, and then delegate data that way.

Comment: @Rarw I agree its not a good idea but, with little information, I was just throwing out different ideas that could be possible. If there are just two or three then I'm not sure it would be a horrible idea or too difficult to debug but I don't know the situation. They can still be separate files and be different enough that you can see where a problem is fairly easy with good debugging skills

Comment: @codeMagic - Agreed. I didn't mean to suggest you thought it was a good idea. I just wanted to make sure she didn't do it lol.

Comment: @Rarw Fair enough...good call :)