# App crashes every time i make an http request

Tags: android, http, crash, request

This is my code 
every time i touch the imageview my app waits about 5 secs and then chrashes

I have the INTERNET permission

On the server side i have a php page that reads the GET and insert it in a database

```
public class Home extends Activity {
ImageView lightbut;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ImageView lightbut = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.light);
    lightbut.setClickable(true); 
    lightbut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("== My activity ===","OnClick is called");
         // Creating HTTP client
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Creating HTTP Post
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://192.168.0.102/HR/index.php?command=ligthsoff");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For ease of use, check out [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidquery). Getting `XML` or `JSON` is as simple as `$.getJSON(url)` or `$.getXML(url)`.

Comment: These days you should use Android's Volley library https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A logcat would be very helpful but its probably from doing network stuff on the `UI`. You should move all of your network code to a background `Thread` such as an `AsyncTask`. This will easily allow you to do the network stuff in the background then update the `UI` if needed in functions that run on the `UI`.

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455858/using-asynctask-to-speed-up-android-app-launch-time/15456047#15456047) that shows the basic structure. Basically, you call the `AsyncTask` from the `UI` such as in your `onClick()` then you do network operations in `doInBackground()` which is called when the task first starts then you can update the `UI` in any of its other methods.

Using the example I referenced, you would just put all of your network stuff, which looks like everything in your `onClick()`, inside the `doInBackground()` method of the example in the link. Then in your `onClick()` you would do something like

```
lightbut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       TalkToServer task = new TalkToServer(); // could pass params to constructor here but might not be needed in this situation
       task.execute();  // could pass in params for `doInBackground()` such as url, etc... but again maybe not needed for this situation 
}
```

Comment: How can i do that? If you gave me a code i would be very thankful!

Comment: I have edited with a link to an example of getting started with it. You also should read the docs because there is important information you need to understand.

Comment: I have edited again with a little more of a description. That should get you started. You can simply make the `AsyncTask` an inner class of your `Activity` if it won't be needed anywhere else. Then you can have access to member variables of the `Activity` as well as access to its functions