# how to start new activity on successful login in the following code?

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-activity

I have following class in my app i am sending username and password to remote server and on server side its matching values and sending respond. Everything working completely fine. I want to ask how can i start new activity after login successful message. I want new activity start when message disappear. QnActivity is the Activity i want to start and LoActivity is my current activity. I have tried so much but not successful. I've also added

```
startActivity(new Intent(LoActivity.this, QnActivity.class));
```

in `public void Move_to_next()` method but its not working.

Java Code-

```
 public class LoActivity extends Activity {

        Intent i;
        Button signin;
        TextView error;
        CheckBox check;
        String name="",pass="";
        byte[] data;
        HttpPost httppost;
        StringBuffer buffer;
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient httpclient;
        InputStream inputStream;
        SharedPreferences app_preferences ;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
        EditText editTextId, editTextP;

        @Override
        public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);
            signin = (Button) findViewById (R.id.signin);
            editTextId = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editTextId);
            editTextP = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editTextP);
            app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check);
            String Str_user = app_preferences.getString("username","0" );
            String Str_pass = app_preferences.getString("password", "0");
            String Str_check = app_preferences.getString("checked", "no");
            if(Str_check.equals("yes"))
            {
                editTextId.setText(Str_user);
                editTextP.setText(Str_pass);
                check.setChecked(true);
            }

            signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    name = editTextId.getText().toString();
                    pass = editTextP.getText().toString();
                    String Str_check2 = app_preferences.getString("checked", "no");
                    if(Str_check2.equals("yes"))
                    {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("username", name);
                        editor.putString("password", pass);
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                    if(name.equals("") || pass.equals(""))
                    {
                         Toast.makeText(Lo.this, "Blank Field..Please Enter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    try {
                        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        httppost = new HttpPost("http://abc.com/register.php");
                        // Add your data
                        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserEmail", name.trim()));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", pass.trim()));
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                        data = new byte[256];

                        buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        int len = 0;
                        while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                        {
                            buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                        }

                        inputStream.close();
                    }

                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoActivity.this, "error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if(buffer.charAt(0)=='Y')
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoActivity.this, "login successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoActivity.this, "Invalid Username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    }
                }
            });

        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                {
                     editor.putString("checked", "yes");
                     editor.commit();
                }
                else
                {
                     editor.putString("checked", "no");
                     editor.commit();
                }
        }
        });
        }
         public void Move_to_next()
         {
             startActivity(new Intent(LoActivity.this, QnActivity.class));

         }
    }
```

Comment: What does "not successful" mean? Does the application crash, does nothing happen, or does something else happen? "It doesn't work" is not a good description of the problem.

Comment: I dont know how to use Asyncthask. The links prvided by codeMagic are good but asynctask is new for me. so i dont know how to merge my code with asynctask code. Plz anyone help me.

Comment: @Tanis.7x after successful login as others said Move_to_next() never called. and logcat show too much work on main thread as others already know. But i dont know how to use asynctask in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a network realted operation on the ui thread. Use a Thread or Asynctask

```
  response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

You will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` post honeycomb if you run network related operaion on the ui thread

And make sure you call `Move_to_next()` in your code.

To invoke `AsyncTask` on the ui thread

```
   new TheTask().execute();
```

AsyncTask

```
   class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
   {
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute()
       {
               super.onPreExecute();
               // dispaly progress dialog 
       } 
       @Override
       protected void doInbackground(Void... params)
       {
           // do network related operation here
           // do not update ui here
          return null; // return result here
       } 
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Void result) // result of background computation received
       {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
            // dimiss dialog
           // update ui here     
       } 
   }
```

Comment: Good catch! I didn't notice that the method wasn't called. But I did stop reading when I saw the ugly `NetworkOnMain` coming ;)

Comment: @Raghunandan please tell me how to implement this in my code.

Comment: @JohnR use asynctask i will post a sample. check it understand and then try

Comment: @JohnR check the post now and this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @Raghunandan sir as suggested by you i make changes in my code. But few errors please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031225/unable-to-launch-activity

Comment: @Raghunandan  Is it possible to call one xml from two activites? like i want to create signup activity.

Comment: @JohnR i am not sure i understand your requirement. But for a single activity you need to have setContentView only once for the activity. It s a bad design if you have more than once. So each activity will have a ui set with setcontentView

Comment: @Raghunandan the link i send you last day i m glad if you help me. Like i have signin.setOnClickListener there. how i add new signup.setOnClickListener there? and what changes i have to made there?

Comment: @Raghunandan if i dont add async task there then i know how to do that but now difficult for me.

Comment: @Raghunandan later i post question and let you inform. I dont know your age but bro. thank you for all your help so nice of you.

Comment: @JohnR glad to help anytime

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to say *why* it isn't working since you haven't told us *how* it isn't working. However, you should move your network calls to another `Thread`. Put this in an `AsyncTask`. Do your network stuff in `doInBackground()`.

Then after the network stuff finishes you can send the result to `onPostExecute()` and call `startActivity()` from there if the login is successful.

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[AsyncTask example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455858/using-asynctask-to-speed-up-android-app-launch-time/15456047#15456047)

Comment: nice you posted the example and the links i was lazy this time din't post the code

Comment: @codeMagic i have little problem hope you help me. i have one issue when i type password its show that digit or alphabet then convert it into dot. i want i press any digit its not show that digit or alphabet show only dot.

Comment: @JohnR you probably want to look at setting a [Password Input Type](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)

Comment: @codeMagic and please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227846/how-to-set-the-value-of-sharedpreferences-in-other-activity

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be, you never call the method `Move_to_next()`

I would suggest calling it once you get a good response from the server, but also, you should take @Ragunandan's advice and run the request on a separate thread.

Comment: nice you pointed that out "you never call the method Move_to_next()". you are right

Comment: @GilMoshayof please tell me how to implement the code suggested by others.

Comment: Can you help me by merging my code with async task please i am very thankful to you.