# how to set the value of sharedPreferences in other activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have two activities in my app. First activity `SplashScreen` and other `SplashActivity`. I have `sharedPreferences` in `SplashScreen` but i want to set value of this true in `SplashActivity`. I think If it is possible to create a method in `SplashActivity` which run only once i.e this method compare the `boolean` value of `SplashScreen` (like this is false at start). After first run its set to true forever and this method is skipped. I've tried a lot to do this but not successful.

SplashScreen-

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TimerTask task;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
       pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       Log.v("","onCreate is calling");
       if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false))
       {
            Log.v("","Before if called");
            setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
            Log.v("","after if called");
            new Handler().postDelayed(csRunnable1, 5000);
       } 
       else 
       {
          new Handler().postDelayed(csRunnable2, 5000);  
       }
   }

   Runnable csRunnable1=new Runnable() 
   {       
       @Override
       public void run() 
       {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, SplashActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();

       }
   };

   Runnable csRunnable2=new Runnable() 
    {      
       @Override
       public void run() 
       {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();

       }
   };
}
```

SplashActivity-

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //////// GAME MENU  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
        playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button settingsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsBtn);
        settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button rulesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rulesBtn);
        rulesBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button exitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
        exitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    /**
     * Listener for game menu
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i;

        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.playBtn :
            //once logged in, load the main page
            //Log.d("LOGIN", "User has started the game");
            //Get Question set //
            List<Question> questions = getQuestionSetFromDb();
            //Initialise Game with retrieved question set ///
            GamePlay c = new GamePlay();
            c.setQuestions(questions);
            c.setNumRounds(getNumQuestions());
            ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c);  
            //Start Game Now.. //
            i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, Constants.PLAYBUTTON);
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.rulesBtn :
            i = new Intent(this, RulesActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, Constants.RULESBUTTON);
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.settingsBtn :
            i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, Constants.SETTINGSBUTTON);
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.exitBtn :
            finish();
            break;
        }

    }
```

I know this is the line i need to edit in `SplashActivity` but whenever i add this my app crash.

```
ed = pref.edit();
ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
ed.commit();
```

Comment: If the point of this is to not need to login again, then don't you actually want it in the `LoginActivity` or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: yes you are right i want to skip LoginActivity when i second time run app.

Comment: and if i set the value true in SplashActivity it means user login once thats what i want.

Comment: Then you want to set that variable to `true` in the `LoginActivity` after a successful login and check in `SplashScreen`. If it is `false` then go to `LoginActivity`. If it is `true` then go to `SplashActivity`

Comment: I already tried that but some problems with that. so i think if i set values in SplashActivity thats best for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are doing something wrong. you can do simply this in splash screen

```
   if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false))
   {
        Log.v("","Before if called");
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        Log.v("","after if called");
        new Handler().postDelayed(csRunnable1, 5000);
        pref.edit().putBoolean("activity_executed", true).commit();
   }
```

or in your splashactivity oncreate call this

```
getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("activity_executed", true).commit();
```

Comment: can you please explain me the meaning of this code. pref.edit().putBoolean("activity_executed", true).commit();

Comment: same actually .. if you see ... like getSharedPreference returns a preferences.. so instead of writing in multiple line you can do it in once.. or you can do like you did.. another thing is do either of my solution .. not both ...

Comment: and one more little help if you dont have problem?

Comment: i have one issue when i type password its show that digit or alphabet then convert it into dot. i want i press any digit its not show that digit or alphabet show only dot. everyone send me this link http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html

Comment: if you set inputtype ass password then the character will be hidden automatically... check android:inputType

Comment: yes i have already done. but when i type password every digit visible for few milli seconds and its easy for other person to see what's your password. i want instant conversion. so that other person not able to see what is the password.

Comment: it is actually the defaut behavior... you can do one thing.. you can set a textwatcher.. whenever a text is changed you can set a * manually there

Comment: ok how to use textwatcher you know any link so that i get help from that.

Comment: just search with textwatcher .. see the doc .. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html.. do some test codes

Comment: need your one more help please check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272345/how-to-start-new-countdowntimer-in-dialog-box-with-remaining-seconds/19272536?noredirect=1#comment28533755_19272536

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272345/how-to-start-new-countdowntimer-in-dialog-box-with-remaining-seconds

Answer (score 0):

Also call this in your SplashActivity

```
onCreate(...){
....
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor ed;
pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ed = pref.edit();
ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
ed.commit();
....
}
```