# how to start new countdowntimer in dialog box with remaining seconds?

Tags: android, button, timer, dialog

In my app i have Countdown Timer and dialog box in same class. when someone press quit button dialog box opens and in it 2 buttons yes and no. I want when someone press quit button timer pause and if someone press no button its resume with remaining seconds. I know for this i have to finish this timer and create new timer with remaining seconds. But i am unable to get remaining seconds. If someone know how to do this please help me.

Code of countdown timer-

```
counterTimer = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
        public void onFinish() {                
                if(currentGame.getRound()==20)
                {
                nextBtn1.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn2.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn3.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn4.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn5.setEnabled(false);
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Time's Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
                }

                else if(currentGame.getRound()==0)
                {
                currentGame.decrementScore();
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        processScreen();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
                }

                else if(currentGame.getRound()<=19)
                {
                        nextBtn1.setEnabled(false);
                        nextBtn2.setEnabled(false);
                        nextBtn3.setEnabled(false);
                        nextBtn4.setEnabled(false);
                        nextBtn5.setEnabled(false);
                        currentGame.decrementScore();
                        final Handler handle = new Handler();
                        Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Time's Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                processScreen();
                            }
                        };
                        handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
                 }
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
                time.setText( ""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
                                }
        };
        counterTimer.start();
    }
```

Code for Dialog Box-

```
if(arg0.getId()==R.id.quit)
        {       
            Button yes, no;
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.FullHeightDialog); 
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1); 
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            counterTimer.cancel(); 
            //to set the message
            TextView message =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvmessagedialogtext);
            message.setText("Are you sure you want to Exit?");
            yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bmessageDialogYes);
            yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
             finish();
             startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));             
                    }
            });

             no = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bmessageDialogNo);
             no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v)  
             {
             dialog.dismiss();
             nextBtn1.setEnabled(true);
             nextBtn2.setEnabled(true);
             nextBtn3.setEnabled(true);
             nextBtn4.setEnabled(true);
             }
             });
             dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: there is no pause for the timer. you need to cancel and restart. to get remaining second you need to store the seconds left when you cancel the timer and use the same when you start the timer again

Comment: i know but dont know how to save left seconds in above code. thank you for ur response.

Comment: you can use shared preferences for the same

Comment: ok is it need too many additions in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog Box Code-

```
 private long remaingtime, starttime = 15000;
    MyCounter timer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);
    nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
            nextBtn1.setEnabled(true);
            nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
            nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
            nextBtn2.setEnabled(true);
            nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
            nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
            nextBtn3.setEnabled(true);
            nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
            nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
            nextBtn4.setEnabled(true);
            nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
            nextBtn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quit);
            nextBtn5.setEnabled(true);
            nextBtn5.setOnClickListener(this);
    timer = new MyCounter(starttime, 1000);
    timer.start();
    }

    if(arg0.getId() == R.id.quit)
            {   
                timer.cancel();
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.FullHeightDialog); 
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                //to set the message
                TextView message =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvmessagedialogtext);
                message.setText("Are you sure you want to Exit?");
                yes = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bmessageDialogYes);
                yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                 startActivity(new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));    
                 finish();
                }
                });

                no = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bmessageDialogNo);
                no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v)  
                {
                dialog.dismiss();
                timer = new MyCounter(remaingtime, 1000);
                timer.start();           
                nextBtn1.setEnabled(true);
                nextBtn2.setEnabled(true);
                nextBtn3.setEnabled(true);
                nextBtn4.setEnabled(true);
                }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
```

Count Down Timer Code-

```
public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer
{
       public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
            {
                super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
                remaingtime = millisUntilFinished;
                time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
                time.setText(""+millisUntilFinished/1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                if(currentGame.getRound()==20)
                {
                nextBtn1.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn2.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn3.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn4.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn5.setEnabled(false);
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Time's Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
                }

                else if(currentGame.getRound()==0)
                {
                currentGame.decrementScore();
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        processScreen();
                    }
                };
                handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
                }

                else if(currentGame.getRound()<=19)
                {
                nextBtn1.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn2.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn3.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn4.setEnabled(false);
                nextBtn5.setEnabled(false);
                currentGame.decrementScore();
                final Handler handle = new Handler();
                Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, "Time's Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
                public void run() 
                {
                  processScreen();
                }
                };
            handle.postDelayed(delay,3000);
            }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like that

```
private final long interval = 1000;
long millisLeft = 90000;

public class MalibuCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

        public MalibuCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Time's up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            millisLeft = millisUntilFinished;
            System.out.println("The milies left is" + millisLeft);  
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

            countDownTimer = new MalibuCountDownTimer(millisLeft, interval);
            countDownTimer.start();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
```

Comment: i've already seen this kind of examples so many. if you able to help me by making little changes in my code. please.

Comment: same way you can achieve when click on quit then call cancel as like pause and again comes in resume state then start the timer with remaining time count

Comment: in your code you are creating different class but i want to do this by adding in my code instead of dreating new one.

Answer (score 0):

Just count the seconds yourself on each tick and use them later to create a new timer.

Comment: in the onTick method, save the remaining seconds somewhere. use them to start the next timer.

Comment: This is trivial to implement, you can figure that out yourself if you know how to start timers.

Comment: i know how to implement but dont know how to get remaining seconds.